# Do we have any option for display google map marker in right side position instead of center point

Tags: google-maps

Do we have any option for display google map marker in right side position instead of center point
**HTML**

```
<div id="map_32" style="width:100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {

    var lan = 11.4602
    var lat = 47.7493

    var infoWindowContent = "Info Content";

    var zoom  = 14;

    createMap( lat, lan,zoom,infoWindowContent );
}

function createMap(lat, lng, zoomVal,infoWindowContent ) {

    var infoText_32 = infoWindowContent;
        infoText_32 = decodeURIComponent(infoText_32);
        infoText_32 = infoText_32.replace(/\+/g, ' ');

    // split infoText into rows
    var rowsInfoText_32 = infoText_32.split("<br>");

    var latlng_32 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

    var mapOptions_32 = new Object();
        mapOptions_32.center = latlng_32;
        mapOptions_32.zoom = zoomVal;
        mapOptions_32.mapTypeId = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
        mapOptions_32.navigationControlOptions = new Object();
        mapOptions_32.navigationControlOptions.style = google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT;
        mapOptions_32.scrollwheel = true;

        //myOptions.navigationControlOptions = {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL};

    var mapCenter_32 = new Object();
        mapCenter_32.position = latlng_32;
        mapCenter_32.title = rowsInfoText_32[0];

        mapCenter_32.icon = 'map-icon.png';

    var map_32 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(""), mapOptions_32);
    var marker_32 = new google.maps.Marker(mapCenter_32);

    // set info window
    if ('' != infoText_32){
        infoText_32 = infoText_32.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
        var infoBox_32 = new Object();
            infoBox_32.content = infoText_32;

        var infowindow_32 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoBox_32);
        // add listener
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker_32, 'click', function(){openInfoWindow_32();});
    }


    if (true == '') {
      // show map, open infoBox and center view
      google.maps.event.addListener(map_32, 'tilesloaded',    
        function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker_32, 'click');});
    }

    marker_32.setMap(map_32); 

    function openInfoWindow_32(){
        infowindow_32.open(map_32,marker_32);
    }
}
```

How we cant set our marker in right side position IN GOOGLE MAP

Let me know if you get any proper clue

Comment: You can make an image with the marker a little to the left and add it in as a [**custom marker**](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers)

Comment: @so_jin_ee There is a better way. Please refer to my answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to define [marker offset](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons) in Google Maps.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:new google.maps.LatLng(36,-80),
  icon: {
    url: 'images/beachflag.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  }
  //more attributes
});
```

This was taken directly from the example on the given URL.

Essentially, it is an object with attributes about the image source (`url`), and the size, origin and positioning values. This is pretty straight forward. For having the marker on the **left** side of the marker, use `anchor: new google.maps.Point(32,32)`, or the height and width of the image. For the image to be on the **right** side of the marker (like the example), use `anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,32)`, or `0` and the height of the marker.